# Add markers to image similar to what the mapping apps do - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, overlay, markers

I am currently using **Xamarin.Forms** and I would like to import an image and be able to add markers to it. Similar to what the mapping apps do, but want to be able to do it from an uploaded image or from taking a photo. I would also Like to be able to set a scale on it after the image was uploaded by placing two or more markers and then entering a measurement between those markers.

*When displaying an image/photo I would like to place markers on them that would have more info about the pinned location on the image. These pins must be saved in a database so that the next time it's opened the markers will be in the correct location as they were placed the first time.*

If anyone knows how I can get started on this, or know of any libraries that allow you to this, it would really be appreciated.

.

**Update**

1. Loading the image from file, camera or url is simple enough.
2. Zooming in and out after the image is loaded was simple enough too. Altering the scale size of the Image by making use of the PinchGesture.
3. Moving the image around ended up being simple too, and it was achieved by using the PanGesture and altering the TranslationX and TranslationY.

.

.......Still searching for a working and reliable solution for adding Pins/Markers at a location on the image and the markers need to have a click or tap event attached to it.

Comment: You should first try to show an image as a map as I mentioned in the last comment that put the image inside a scrollview. But how do you know the pinned location on the image?

Comment: well, that is what I am trying to find out.